# Focus between EditText and ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

My row in list that has editText in it, beside other things. If I set `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on editText, I am able to select my entire row, highlight it, get data I need, but I no longer can edit my editText, because keyboard doesn't pop up. If I set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`, then I can edit editText, but i can't click on entire row, highlight it, get data. How can I achieve both?

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` isn't adapted for inputs. It keeps in memory only visible items + 2. So even if you will achieve the that what you want, all your edits will dessapear after every time, your `EditText` leaves the screen.

Take a look at **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)** view documentation. This class is better adapted to this kind of stuff.

**UPD**

Actually, there is a [tutorial](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/) exactly for foucsable `EditTexts` in `ListView`. But as you see, it was relevant for 2011.